# Problems with the display of constants in IDA Pro pseudocode

Tags: ida

There is an elf x64 file, the pseudocode of IDA Pro 7.6 shows that a constant is 0xFFFFFFFD, but in fact it is "3" in the source code, how can I change it to show "3" in the pseudocode. As shown in the following figure.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can change the display of the constant by right-clicking. "Invert sign" is the one you want here, but there are seven options on that menu. That option will show you "-3" for the constant you have selected. None of them will show you "3", because all of the numbers are negative. You are mistaken about the contents of the source code.